# Permutation test / create a function for event dummy for different dates

Tags: r, permutation

This question will be very difficult to formulate, but essentially I'm doing an event study for my bachelor thesis and would like to examine how significant the coefficient for my interaction effect is.

What I find difficult is that I want to run a fixed effect regression in which the interaction effect, treatment * event, change dates for the event window. I want to create a function that makes the dummy variable for the event to take on different dates (it should be a length of 7 consequitive days) and that the start date of these seven dates change.

The equation looks something like this:

return = intercept + ROA + Tanibility + ... + Event + Treatment group + Event * Treatment group

Then I would like to run the fixed effects regression with these different dummies to then extract the estimates for the dummy. This would enable me to compare the coefficent estimate obtained for the actual event date with the "fake" event days.

Thank you in advance if you decide to help me :)

I have tried to find different functions and I have only found permutation tests that test the means of the two groups.

I've tried to make a function and have this:

```
set.seed(1000)

N <- 10^3-1 # Number of permutations
resultX <- numeric(N)
for(i in 1:N){ 
index1 <- sample(length(merged_df), size = 7, replace = FALSE)
df_c$eventdummy <- ifelse(merged_df$day == index1, 1, 0)

resultX[i] <- plm(ret ~ sse*eventdummy + 
                    sse + 
                    eventdummy + 
                    roa + 
                    leverage +  
                    mtb + 
                    tangibility, 
                    data = merged_df,
                    index = c("entity"), 
                    model = "within")
}
```